# Multithread Insert csvreader row into postgres connected by psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, python-multithreading

I have a pipeline that reads gzipped csv data into python and inserts the data into a postgres database, row by row, connected using psycopg2. I've created a thread connection pool, but I'm unsure how to leverage this to insert each row in a separate thread, rather than inserting sequentially. The internet gives me mixed messages if this is even possible, and I have some experience with the threading python module but not a lot.

The pipeline currently is successful, but it is slow, and I'm hoping that it can be made faster by inserting the rows across threads, rather than sequentially.

The following code is simplified for clarity:

```
main script

for row in reader:
    insertrows(configs, row)
```

```
insertrows script

threadpool = pool.ThreadedConnectionPool(5, 20, database=dbname, port=port, user=user, password=password, host=host)
con = threadpool.getconn()
con.autocommit = True
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES row")
cur.close()
threadpool.putconn(con)
```

What I would like to do is rather than looping through the rows, create something like the threading example in [this link](https://www.toptal.com/python/beginners-guide-to-concurrency-and-parallelism-in-python) but without a strong frame of reference for multithreading it's hard for me to figure out how to write something like that for my purposes.

Comment: Have you tried bulk inserting the data rather than using threads?

Comment: I don't want to bulk insert because I want the pipeline to be robust to big datasets, but thank you for the suggestion. Haven't had a chance to try this yet, but I'm going to try just holding the connection open rather than reconnecting for each insert. If I can do that as a threaded connection pool all the better, but I'd still like to know how to leverage that possibility anyway...

Comment: To follow up, not bulking was also really inefficient, so now I'm batching rows in 100,000 in addition to holding open the connection, both of which make the pipeline faster. But I'd still like to figure out how to actually leverage multi-threaded inserts...